# ExtJS: FireEvent instead of referencing direct elements

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, separation-of-concerns

In Sencha Touch there was this beautiful possibillity to separate the View from Controller: in the View, for example in Button Click-Handler, we just used

```
this.fireEvent('loginTapped', this.getUsername(), this.getUserPass())
```

And the controller was just listenin to "loginTapped", and not linked with the button itself.

In ExtJS I see currently no possibiliity to manage that separation.

In every example the elements are directly referenced in the Controller by this QuerySelector.

For me that seems, on architecture perspective not very good, the controller has to know a lot of implementation details of the view.

Anyone knows how to manage that analog to the sencha touch way? Or am I really forced to work like that in ExtJS.

Comment: You can follow exactly the same patterns, the controller code started out from a common base, they're very similar.

Comment: So 1:1 declare refs: {} etc.? I used it, but the controller doesn't receive any events in that case

Comment: From memory the only significant difference is that Ext doesn't support using refs as part of the query selectors.

Comment: so how do i listen to the fireEvent-stuff then? In Sencha Touch there were this refs where you keep references to whole containers

Comment: In the same way. If your query was `someref foo`, then you replace it with `queryforsomeref foo`.